# Как сделать HTML5 баннер для AdRiver?

Tags: html5, flash

Есть анимированный баннер, сделанный в Adobe Flash.
Задача: адаптировать HTML5 версию баннера для AdRiver, вот [требования](http://www.adriver.ru/doc/ban/spec/spec_576.html)

Мои знания html5 баннеров заканчиваются на том, чтобы сохранить баннер из Adobe Flash в формате .html. Документация Адривера вызывает легкую панику...)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, самый безболезненный способ адаптировать флешовый баннер для AdRiver. За что хвататься, есть ли какие-то инструкцию или видеоуроки для чайников?

Как применять типы кода, указанные в документации Адривера: "Тип кода: фреймовый, Poster, AjaxJS, Extension".

И еще один, возможно, глупый вопрос. Можно ли вообще адаптировать баннер, сделанный в Adobe Flash, под требования HTML5 баннера для AdRiver? Или нужно переделывать баннер с нуля в каком-то другом ПО, специализированном для создания HTML баннеров (Google Web Designer, наверное)?

Спасибо заранее)

Comment: Так html5 или flash?

Comment: сделала апдэйт вопроса. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте Adobe Animate CC. Это тот же флеш, но с возможностью преобразовать проект из flash в html5 canvas (Команды>Преобразовать в другой формат документа). Но если были скрипты, они закомментируются. А так всю анимацию можно будет править дальше. Потом публикуйте, но снимите галку с "создать лист спрайта".

А для адривера, нужно выбрать простой html баннер. Открыть опубликованный код в текстовом редакторе и повставлять все строки, что указаны на сайте адривера для html-банеров.